# find first span in a list and change to link

Tags: jquery

I have a list made up of links and spans for those that cant be viewable yet. For example:

```
<div id="lessons_list">
 <a href="course1.php" id="course1">course 1 </a>
 <a href="course2.php" id="course2">course 2 </a>
 <a href="course3.php" id="course3">course 3 </a>
 <span href="course4.php" id="course4">course 4 </span>
 <span href="course4.php" id="course5">course 5 </span>
</div>
```

Im trying to use jquery to find the first span in that list (in this case course 4) and turn it into a link, which is trickier than i thought. This is as far as i got with it, not sure why its not working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#lessons_list').find('span:first', function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).replaceWith('<a href='+href+'>'+$(this).html()+'</a>');

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `find` supports the second argument? https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Be advised `<span href="course4.php"` is invalid html

Comment: @Huangism is right. You could use `data-href` instead.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Would be best to do so

Comment: @Huangism, im having trouble with the original code yury posted on my live site, could you check out the jsfiddles i posted below and see if you could let me know what im missing.

Comment: @XanaFernandezMartin I think Yury already answered your question in the comment, mark it correct if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `find` supports some sort of callback as the second argument. `replaceWith` does.

```
$(function() {
        $('#lessons_list').find('span:first').replaceWith(function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            return '<a href='+href+'>'+$(this).html()+'</a>';
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/0xj2t49o/).

*UPD*
Using data attributes

```
<span data-href="course4.php" id="course4">course 4 </span>


$(function() {
        $('#lessons_list').find('span:first').replaceWith(function() {
            var href = $(this).data('href'); 
            return '<a href='+href+'>'+$(this).html()+'</a>';
    });
})
```

Comment: No problem. By the way as @Huangism has noted you'd better use `data-*` for custom attributes.

Comment: hi yury, for some reason its not working in the final code.... it tried editing the jsfiddle with the actual html, and it didnt work either.... the weird thing was, when i tidied up the html and tried it again in jsfiddle it worked fine. any idea why that would be?

Comment: actually it looks like having a span with an href might be the problem (since it got removed when the html was tidied up)... this is getting outputed from php, maybe if i changed href to something else? any suggestions

Comment: i also added data-href and didnt work.... heres the non working fiddle with actual code i just copied pasted https://jsfiddle.net/nwuL36pr/1/   and here is the tidied up version https://jsfiddle.net/298oqq19/

Comment: Because it's not `href` anymore it is `.attr('data-href')`
https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/nwuL36pr/3/
But it is more canonical to use `data` instead of `attr` to access data-attributes. https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/nwuL36pr/2/